# dplyr::select_if(., is.numeric) super slow

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

This (the part `y = ...`) runs abnormally slowly:

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 10000
p <- 1000


x <- as.tbl(as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n * p), nc = p)))
y = x %>%
  select_if(., is.numeric)
```

in fact, it is one of the smallest part of my data cleaning code. Is there a better way to do this?

(dplyr 0.7.1)

Comment: `x[sapply(x, is.numeric)]` should be more fast

Comment: Probably related to [this open issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2813) on the dplyr repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This runs faster despite being more clunky:

```
x %>% select(which(lapply(x,class) == "numeric"))
```

Comment: wao. Your code is about 1000 times faster on my (much bigger dataset)!